# Start a new line like a word document

Tags: java

I need my program to wrap lines after a certain number of characters, like in Microsoft word. The program is supposed to take large text and convert it to all upper or lower. It ends up running off the end of the screen and I can't afford a bigger one.

All I currently have is one that wraps after characters, possibly in the middle of a word, which ends up looking weird.

```
int linecount = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < ask.length(); i++) 
  {
     askformat += ask.charAt(i);
     linecount++;
     if (linecount==50)
     {
     askformat += '\n';
     linecount = 0;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Is your application a GUI application or a Console application? If it's a console application, the console will do it for you. If it is a GUI application then use a `JTextPane`/`JTextArea` with line-wrapping enabled to view the text

Comment: @BackSlash It is a GUI application, thank you very much.

Comment: Use `StringBuilder.append` (later `toString`) instead of `String +=` which is radically faster for large text.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a GUI application and you are using a JTextArea, you simply need to add the following line:

```
jta.setLineWrap(true)
jta.setWrapStyleWord(true)
```

Where jta is your JTextArea instance.

See [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setWrapStyleWord%28boolean%29).

**EDIT:** Added `setWrapStyleWord` as per @BackSlash's suggestion, which is more appropriate if the text being entered is expected to have whitespace breaks, like real text. This is the same way that a word document would wrap. For clarification, the difference is that just `setLineWrap` will add new lines after any character boundary (so the lines will split, when the full width of the area of the JTA is filled irrespective of if it is mid word or not) whereas with `setWrapStyleWord` it will add new lines at whitespace boundaries, meaning that the text will be wrapped after a word (unless there is no whitespace on the line in whichcase it, will exhibit the same functionality as `setLineWrap`)

Comment: I would also use `jta.setWrapStyleWord(true)`, otherwise the result will be the same (breaking words)

Comment: I think you also have to use `jta.setLineWrap(true)`, the API for `setWrapStyleWord` says: _Sets the style of wrapping used_ ***if the text area is wrapping lines***